# ASP.NET MVC Ajax request error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 & C#.
Basically when I click a button on my website, it should generate a report in async manner. Generating report takes ~10 minutes. 
Also while the report is being generated asynchronously, I need to be able to keep on using other area of the website.

So I have mainly below look alike ajax request that I call on generate report button click. I also have my async action method in place properly.
If I hit the generate report button then it starts processing it and display "Report generated!" once the report is generated (like in 10 minutes).

That's fine. But after clicking the button, if I try to access any other area on the website (like clicking on other tab/button/etc) then it immediately displays me the error message "An error occurred!", which is coming from ajax error section - See below code. 
Also it completes the report generation asynchronously fine. But it just shows me the error message right after I hit the button!

This seems weird to me. Please guide me as what's happening here and help me to fix this. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(html){
    alert("Report generated!");
  },
  error: function(e) {
     alert("An error occurred!");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code runs within the context of the page.  When you try to navigate around your website the current page will be unloaded and the javascript objects for the page will be destroyed.  This is what is triggering the error callback, the ajax object knows the page is being unloaded and letting you know that the call failed before it is destroyed.

To solve your problem you should look into generating the report on a background thread on the server and have a separate page which can poll for the status of the report and allow the user to download it when finished.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that makes sense. So my action method returns true/false on completion of the async task. I'm planning to introduce notification label (as a partial view maybe) in the layout page. So once my method returns true, how can I show the notification label that the report is generated. I'm sorry, but I'm kinda new in MVC world. Can you suggest me options to achieve this? Thanks!